# Request to expo api failed

Tags: react-native, expo, network-connection

I attempted to run a simple app with the Expo Docs command `npm create-expo-app my-app`, but I am encountering the following Fetch error:

[image]

When I input this URL directly into my browser, I receive a response. However, when I execute `npm start`, it presents an error. I have no idea what's happening.

I was expecting to run my app, which didn't happen.